# How to perform full word searching in Lunr.js for Svelte?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, wordsearch, lunrjs

Please go through the sample svelte application which uses the Lunr.js library to perform searching through a document:
[Lunr.js - Svelte](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-tfuvms?file=src/App.svelte)

I am trying to search for the term 'example'. However, I am only able to get the expected result if I type 'exampl'. I would like to search through the document and print results for every matching item when pressing a key. I tried using the wildcard (*) property like so:

`results = index.search(query + '*')`

Using this method, I am able to print the matching result for every key press. However, when I type the full word 'example', the result is empty.

How can I perform single, partial, and full word searching?